# Synchronizing iBooks with iPad/iPhone does not synchronize collections

Tags: books

When I synchronize iBooks from my MacBook to my iPhone/iPad via iTunes it synchronizes all my books, but it doesn't synchronize the collections (they are all just dumped into one single collection).

How do I synchronize the collections?

EDIT: the `Settings -> Synchronize bookmarks, highlights, and collections across devices" option is enabled.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/245399/88313).  It's a similar question but doesn't have an accepted answer yet.

Comment: This [site](https://miapple.me/fixing-ibooks-not-syncing-pdf-files-epub-books-mac-ipad-iphone/) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings/Ibooks and turn on "Sync Collections" (also sync bookmarks and comments if you want that too).

Comment: If you mean `Settings -> Synchronize bookmarks, highlights, and collections across devices` it is turned on :/